# Reloading Tapestry layout and other components in development?

Tags: intellij-idea, tapestry

**How can I make changes to tml files - like for layout and other components - quickly visible via F5 in the browser?** At the moment I keep those files under the src/main/-folder next to the java class. I already tried to 'repackage' the file but it isn't picked up by Tapestry - it only works for tmls under /webapps.

PS: Using IntelliJ with Maven

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heureka! I found an answer deep in the IntelliJ forum:

> Try to add .tml pattern to Settings /
>   Compiler / Resource patterns, similar
>   to patterns already provided there.

IntelliJ didn't actually 'repackage' the tml files when they weren't under webapp/ before (although it did 'say' it - that's just mean!).

Answer (score 1):

I [found](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tapestry-users/201204.mbox/%3CCBAF4A28.1A796%25gbodet@financeactive.com%3E) that rebuilding the project by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> (or manually from the *Build->Make Project* menu option) and then reload the page in the browser will cause the changes to propagate.

Note: My **.tml* files are located in the *src/main/resources/company-name/components* and *src/main/resources/company-name/pages* folders, which is the default location if you create your project using the `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://tapestry.apache.org` command.

IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 11.1.1